# How to set <a class="class"> to default property given <a>'s property already define in css

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, colors, default

My web pages have a lot of `<a>` without class and their property were set in css as below:

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}

a:hover, a:active{
color:green;
}
```

And now I have `<a>` tags that with `class="tnc"` and I want it to have the default property which is blue color text with underline and when active it change to red color text.

I tried this but not work:

```
a.tnc{
color: initial;
text-decoration: initial;
}

a.tnc:hover, a.tnc:active{
color: initial;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

```css
a:hover, a:active{
 color:green;
}

a.tnc{
 color: initial !important; 
 text-decoration: initial;
}

a.tnc:hover, a.tnc:active{
 color: initial;
}
```

```html
I agree with the <a class="tnc" href="#">terms and conditions</a>
```

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `initial` doesn't work like that.

The initial value is a defined value per CSS property; *not* per HTML element.

Go to [MDN for the color property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color):

> Initial value Varies from one browser to another

So for the color property: if you want a uniform color - you shouldn't use the value initial.

So to get the correct styles for the tnc class - just reset the properties with  the necessary values:

```
a.tnc{
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.tnc:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}

a:hover, a:active{
color:green;
}

a.tnc{
color: blue;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a.tnc:hover{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Default Anchor</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tnc">Anchor with class tnc</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.tnc{
color: initial !important;
text-decoration: initial !important;
}

a.tnc:hover, a.tnc:active{
color: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you post html

Comment: well initial will set it to black color

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not` selector

```css
a:not(.tnc) {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:not(.tnc):hover,
a:not(.tnc):active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a><br>
<a href="#">Test</a><br>
<a href="#">Test</a><br>
<a href="#">Test</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tnc">Test</a><br>
<a href="#">Test</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tnc">Test</a>
```